# Уникальный id поста

Tags: php, база-данных, sql

Добрый вечер.

Есть структура sql таблицы:

```
id post_id  accaunt    post
1     1         1     ля-ля
2     2         1     ля-ля
3     1         2     ля-ля
4     2         2     ля-ля
5     3         2     ля-ля
6     3         1     ля-ля
7     4         1     ля-ля
8     4         2     ля-ля
```

id идет автоинкрементом. Естественно, добавляется цифра автоматом по порядку.
Как можно сделать, чтобы у записи post_id добавлялся типа автоинкремента по порядку, причем для разных записей accaunt, ну то есть

```
accaunt 1
id - 1,2,3, 4, 5...
post_id 1,2,3, 4, 5...

accaunt 2
id - 1,2,3, 4, 5...
post_id 1,2,3, 4, 5...
```

Спасибо всем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Автоинкримент возможен только один. Но возникает вопрос. Если у Вас два поля будут одинаковы по значению - зачем два?
Если так уж надо сделать, то могу предложить два варианта:

1. Перед добавлением записи в таблицу брать последний id (select MAX(id) from `table`) и в сам запрос добавления подставлять для post_id = id++;
2. После добавления записи брать последний добавленный id (в случае базового mysql $last_id = mysql_insert_id() ). И отправлять запрос на обновление записи (update `table` set `post_id` = '".$last_id."' where `id` = '".$last_id."' ).

Оба варианта рабочие, но, по мне, второй самый оптимальный.